# Heroku Apache Kafka Configuration with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, heroku, apache-kafka

I have found lots of sample project related to configuration of apache kafka with spring boot, I tried some of them, it is working good on my windows but when i try to run them on heroku, they give me SSL connection error while connecting with apache kafka on heroku.

Here is my configuration class beans for producer and consumer

```
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

    config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "URL");
    config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "URL");
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "xyz");
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}


@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}
```

Comment: You didn't add any SSL settings here. Any settings you added to Dropwizard will work in Spring factories as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded dependencies for spring boot to 2.2.1.RELEASE, apache kafka to 2.3.3.RELEASE and updated my configuration class as below, it configured successfully with apache kafka on heroku

```
private Map<String, Object> buildDefaults() {
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
List<String> hostPorts = Lists.newArrayList();

for (String url : Splitter.on(",").split(checkNotNull(getenv("KAFKA_URL")))) { 
    try {
    URI uri = new URI(url);
    hostPorts.add(format("%s:%d", uri.getHost(), uri.getPort()));

    switch (uri.getScheme()) {
        case "kafka":
        properties.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "PLAINTEXT");
        break;
        case "kafka+ssl":
        properties.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SSL");

        try {
            EnvKeyStore envTrustStore = EnvKeyStore.createWithRandomPassword("KAFKA_TRUSTED_CERT");
            EnvKeyStore envKeyStore = EnvKeyStore.createWithRandomPassword("KAFKA_CLIENT_CERT_KEY", "KAFKA_CLIENT_CERT");

            File trustStore = envTrustStore.storeTemp();
            File keyStore = envKeyStore.storeTemp();

            properties.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_TYPE_CONFIG, envTrustStore.type());
            properties.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, trustStore.getAbsolutePath());
            properties.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, envTrustStore.password());
            properties.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_TYPE_CONFIG, envKeyStore.type());
            properties.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, keyStore.getAbsolutePath());
            properties.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, envKeyStore.password());
            properties.put(SslConfigs.SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM_CONFIG, "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("There was a problem creating the Kafka key stores", e);
        }
        break;
        default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(format("unknown scheme; %s", uri.getScheme()));
    }
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

properties.put(CommonClientConfigs.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, Joiner.on(",").join(hostPorts));
return properties;
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
Map<String, Object> config = buildDefaults();

config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
Map<String, Object> config = buildDefaults();
config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "xyz");
config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
return factory;
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to configure the truststore as mentioned in the [Heroku Kafka documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/kafka-on-heroku#using-kafka-in-java-applications).

An example using [env-keystore](https://github.com/heroku/env-keystore) might look like this:

```
EnvKeyStore envTrustStore = EnvKeyStore.createWithRandomPassword("KAFKA_TRUSTED_CERT");
EnvKeyStore envKeyStore = EnvKeyStore.createWithRandomPassword("KAFKA_CLIENT_CERT_KEY", "KAFKA_CLIENT_CERT");

File trustStore = envTrustStore.storeTemp();
File keyStore = envKeyStore.storeTemp();

properties.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_TYPE_CONFIG, envTrustStore.type());
properties.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, trustStore.getAbsolutePath());
properties.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, envTrustStore.password());
properties.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_TYPE_CONFIG, envKeyStore.type());
properties.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, keyStore.getAbsolutePath());
properties.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, envKeyStore.password());
```

For a full example see [this Github repo](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-kafka-demo-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/heroku/kafka/demo/KafkaConfig.java).

Comment: yes i had this repository already but it was using dependencies related to dropwizard. i was needed about spring boot.
DefaultKafkaProducerFactory can accept Map not Properties Object.

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible Kafka is having SASL (JAAS) authentication over TLS. Please double check this and add some additional config properties.

Comment: I checked additional configuration properties, I couldn't find any property that allow me to add SSL certificate, SSL key and etc,  I configured kafka with dropwizard framework, it configured and connected perfect but with spring boot, i am unable to find properties related to SSL configuration.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqar Did you see the `ssl.*` properties? https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs

Comment: What is JASIG? Kafka doesn't use it, AFAIK

Comment: Oh yes. I'll correct myself, I thought about SASL and the related JAAS file

Comment: @cricket_007, thanks,  I checked configuration from given links, I added those properties, upgraded kafka and spring boot dependencies in pom.xml, it configured and connected successfully.